# Django DetailView form dont save data

Tags: django

I have a `DetailView`, and need add a form to user contact.

views.py

```
class ProductView(FormView, DetailView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'product_detail.html'
    form_class = NotificationForm
    success_url = '/products/'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return FormView.post(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
```

forms.py

```
class NotificationForm(ModelForm):
    ..."""some fields"""
    class Meta:
        model = Notification
        fields = [
            'usernameclient',
            'emailclient',
            'emailclient_confirmation',
            'phoneclient',
            'messageclient',
            ]
```

The model `Notification` is where is stored the data from that form

models.py

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ..."""some fields"""
```

I dont understand yet how django workflow with forms. After the submition is correct rediretc to `success_url`, but nothing is save in db... What is missing?

Comment: A `FormView` does *not* save the form, a `CreateVIew` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `FormView` does *not* save the form, a `CreateView` does. You can save the form with:

```
class ProductView(FormView, DetailView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'product_detail.html'
    form_class = NotificationForm
    success_url = '/products/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: tks for atention... the `Notification` model have 2 fk, models `User, Product`, how way i need go to pass error :`IntegrityError at /product/1
NOT NULL constraint failed: users_notification.product_id`

Comment: You should pass values to the instance before saving the form, so `form.instance.product_id = <id-of-the-product>`, the same for the `user` field.

Comment: tks man perfect, i use static id like `1`... but how i get the dinamic current id?

Comment: @MagicHat: if there is a URL parameter, like `<int:pk>`, you can use `self.kwargs['pk']` to obtain the value for the URL parameter.